# Canvas added to YouTube is not visible

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, youtube, webgl

I'm following [the WebGL tutorial from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Getting_started_with_WebGL) ([code](https://github.com/mdn/webgl-examples/tree/gh-pages/tutorial/sample1), [demo (black rectangle)](https://mdn.github.io/webgl-examples/tutorial/sample1/)) to create a WebGL canvas.

The goal is a userscript (with WebGL shaders, i.e. video effects) for YouTube. So I opened a YouTube video page and put the code below (from the link above) into the JavaScript console. The canvas got created, but it is invisible.

The canvas inherits a lot of CSS from YouTube by default. Am I overlooking some CSS properties that make it invisible? What to look out for in such cases? It should be black.

```
let container = document.getElementsByClassName( 'video-stream html5-main-video' )[0].parentElement;
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
canvas.setAttribute('id', 'glcanvas')
canvas.setAttribute('width', '1000')
canvas.setAttribute('height', '1000')
container.appendChild(canvas)

// Initialize the GL context
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

// Set clear color to black, fully opaque
gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
// Clear the color buffer with specified clear color
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your canvas is there, but it's not on-top.  Set some additional CSS for positioning.  For example:

```
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks! Via the console: `canvas.setAttribute('style', 'position: fixed; z-index: 1000;')`

Comment: Why do all `position` options except `fixed` make it invisible, even despite the high `z-index`?

Comment: @root `z-index` has no effect without positioning.  See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: Your link says that `z-index` works for "any `position` other than `static`". But in my case, none of them except `fixed` make the element visible, even though `z-index` is always `1000`. I don't see why.